# Prove that $\liminf_{x \to p} f(x) \ge f(p)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : A \to \mathbb{R} $ and let $ p \in A$ be  a limit point of  $A$ .Then prove that  $f$ is lower semicontinious   at $p$   if and only if $\liminf_{x \to p} f(x) \ge f(p)$

**My attempt**: since  $p$ is a limit point of $A \implies  B(p, \epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset.$
we know that for  every $\epsilon >0$ there exist  $\delta >0$

Therefore we can say that  $B(p, \delta) \cap A \neq \emptyset.$

Now  assume that  $f$ is lower semicontinious at $p$ .Then $f(p) -\epsilon  <f(x)$ for all  $x \in B(p, \delta) \cap A \neq \emptyset.$

After that im not able to proceed further

Comment: That is one of several (equivalent) *definitions* for lower semicontinuity. You might want to clarify which definition you are using.

Comment: @MartinR      that  mean  no need to proof the statement .Am i right ?

Comment: It  still makes sense to ask if two different defintions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two definitions are equivalent:

1. $f$ is lower semicontinuous at $p$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
   $$
    f(x) > f(p) - \epsilon
   $$
   for all $x \in B_\delta(p) \cap  A$.
2. $f$ is lower semicontinuous at $p$ if $\liminf_{x \to p} f(x) \ge f(p)$.

---

$(1) \Rightarrow (2):$  For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$
 f(x) > f(p) - \epsilon
$
for all $x \in A$ with $|x-p| < \delta$. It follows that
$$
 \liminf_{x \to p} f(x) \ge f(p) - \epsilon \, ,
$$
and since this holds for all $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
 \liminf_{x \to p} f(x) \ge f(p) \, .
$$

---

$\neg (1) \Rightarrow \neg(2):$ If $(1)$ does not hold then there is a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$
$$
 f(x) \le f(p) - \epsilon
$$
for some $x \in A$ with $0 < |x-p| < \delta$. It follows that
$$
\liminf_{x \to p} f(x) = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \, \bigl( \inf \{ f(x) \mid x \in B_\delta(p) \setminus \{p \} \} \bigr) \\
\le f(p) - \epsilon < f(p) \, ,
$$
i.e. $(2)$ does not hold.

Comment: In sentence  $\neg (1) \Rightarrow \neg(2)$ what is  the meaning of this symbolics $\neg?$

Comment: @jasmine: It is the symbol for “negation.” I proved $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ by [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).